# Store values from csv file to an array Ubuntu

Tags: bash, ubuntu-18.04

I am very new to scripting programming in Ubuntu. I have to solve the following question: I have a csv file from which I need to extract column 11, and from this column I have to take lines from 3 to 5, which are numerical values. Then I have to save these 3 values in an array. How could I do this without using a script (only a line of commands)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please include sample data and desired results. It's difficult to understand otherwise. Also, why the constraints on no-scripting, single line? Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Could you share that attempt as it might help us where we need to guide to get you to a workable solution (there is often times many ways to solve problems like this).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
arr=( $(awk -F, 'NR >=3 && NR <=5{print $11}' file) )
```

**`arr=( )`** : [Storing in bash array](https://opensource.com/article/18/5/you-dont-know-bash-intro-bash-arrays)

**`$()`** : [Command substitution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/147420/what-is-in-a-command)

**`awk -F, 'NR >=3 && NR <=5{print $11}' file`** : 
Go through the file line by line and only when the line number is >= 3 && <= 5, print the 11th column. This would yield as newline separated output. This output is used to feed bash array.

Read the article about [awk basics](https://linuxhandbook.com/awk-command-tutorial/) to learn more about awk.